# correct way to create symlink in deploy.rb

Tags: deployment, capistrano, symlink

I have an error when i deploy an application:

```
    [neon.locum.ru] executing command
*** [err :: neon.locum.ru] find: `/home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/releases/20130116145843/public/images /home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/releases/20130116145843/public/stylesheets /home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/releases/20130116145843/public/javascripts': Нет такого файла или каталога
    command finished in 91ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-01-16 16:58:45 executing `make_images_link'
  * executing "ln -s /home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/shared/public/images /home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/releases/20130116145843/public/images"
```

As you see it's because first it tries to find /public/images dir. and only then creates a symlink for that directory.
beggining of my deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
after "deploy:update_code", :make_images_link
task :make_images_link, roles => :app do
  images_dir = "#{shared_path}/public/images"
  run "ln -s #{images_dir} #{release_path}/public/images"
end
```

the deploy finishes

```
Gem.source_index called from /home/hosting_grandinvest/projects/demo/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
master process ready
worker=0 ready
reaped #<Process::Status: pid=18656,exited(0)> worker=0
master complete
```

in public/images dir are located some files used by css ( `background: url(/images/front/logo.gif) no-repeat 0 0;`) and they are Not displayed !but when i try to access these files directly
(`http://hosting.net/images/front/logo.gif`) i can see them!

Any suggestions  on how to solve this error and make capistrano work?

**UPDATE 1**
I've included public/images/front in repo and after code deployment swap empty folder with a link

```
after "deploy:update_code", :make_images_link
task :make_images_link, roles => :app do
  images_dir = "#{shared_path}/public/images"
  realease_images = "#{release_path}/public/images"
  run "rm -rf #{realease_images}"
  run "ln -s #{images_dir} #{realease_images}"
end
```

When i deploy error still exists, but images appeared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i've included 'public'images' dir in my repository.
and as step 2 i run a callback that i've specified in update 1.